# Line breakes missing when using tail command

Tags: terminal, tail

I'm using the tail command to monitor a log file on Os X.

command: tail -f path_to_file

When viewing the result in the terminal window, the line breaks are missing.

The log statements have '\r' to create a new line. It seems this character is skipped by the tail app.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to convert `\r` to `\n` with `sed`. If it is available on Os X

```
tail -f path_to_file | sed 's/\\r/\n/g'
```